# Can't start Tomcat on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, tomcat, liferay

I installed Tomcat on Ubuntu. Then I created a new user. Then did:

```
liferay@web-svr:~/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/bin$ chmod +x *.sh
```

Afterwards, I added `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` in bash like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/etc/jdk1.7.0_07
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Then I started Tomcat:

```
 liferay@web-svr:~/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/bin$ sh startup.sh
```

And I get this error:

```
liferay@web-svr:~/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/bin$ sh startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/logs/catalina.out’: Permission denied
./catalina.sh: 389: ./catalina.sh: cannot create /home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied
```

I did:

```
su admin
chmod 755  /home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/logs/
```

But that doesn't help. What can be wrong?

**UPDATE**
OK I did:

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/logs/catalina.out
```

And now when I start Tomcat I get this error:

```
liferay@web-svr:~/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/bin$ sh startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

**UPDATE2**

I have a mistake in JAVA_HOME. Now i have it correct. But When i start a tomcat i still have same output and in catalina.out i have ~1000 lines of errors and line:

```
июл 17, 2013 8:48:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 24802 ms
```

And in myhost:80 i have a blank page and on myhost:8080 i have 404 in FireBug and blank page in browser.

Answer (score 2):

This *is* a line of error:

```
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/logs/catalina.out’: Permission denied
./catalina.sh: 389: ./catalina.sh: cannot create /home/liferay/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied
```

Everything you posted after you fixed the permissions *is not* an error, those are simply log messages informing you that the server started up and what specifically happened during startup.

To see if tomcat is up and running you can try `netstat -l` and/or check your .conf for whether port 80 or 8080 or something totally different is configured.

It simply showing a blank page at the root `/` is not necessarily a sign of a problem as well, it also depends on what was configured in the tomcat and the liferay installation. To further support you on this a more specific topic is needed.